# how to find the value of an input in php?

Tags: php, html

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="ijmOOuuJ265ToFAO" />
```

Hi, could you help me find the value of this input, using php? I need to get this value "ijmOOuuJ265ToFAO", this value will change every time a request is made.

Comment: spanish bro. This is stack overflow is spanish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jonnakings123 please keep in mind that this is a spanish forum.

Para obtener el valor del input debes agregar un código JavaScript y utilizar la función getElementById. Tambien incluir un id al input.
El código quedaría como el que sigue

```
<div class="row">
    <input id="form_key" name="form_key" type="hidden" value="ijmOOuuJ265ToFAO" />
</div>

<script>
    valor = document.getElementById("form_key").value;
    alert(valor);
</script>
```

Como referencia sobre como utilizar estas funciones puedes consultar [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816863/how-to-use-document-getelementbyname-and-getelementbytag)

Comment: Consejo: cuando las preguntas están en otro idioma es preferible no responderlas pues terminan cerradas, anexo tienes la reputación necesaria para dejarle un comentario y guiarlo